# dict.get() return value if dict value is None

Tags: python

Is there a way to return another value if the value in a dict is `None`, using a similar method like `get`?

For example:

```
my_dict = {
 "my_key": None
}
```

What I want to achieve is similar to this logic:

```
my_variable = my_dict.get("my_key", "Not None")
# After executing the line above the value of my_variable should be "Not None"
```

I know `get` checks if the key exist in the dict and if the key does not exist, returns the second parameter. Is there a similar method or one-liner to do this?

Comment: What do you want if `my_key` isn't present, `None` or `"Not None"`?

Comment: My main script defaults every key to `None`, so it is always assumed that the key is always present in the dict.

Comment: Then why not just default to the value you actually want?

Comment: My statement above seems confusing. So if the parameter isn't passed, its key will be default to `None`, else it would be assigned to something else before reaching the line where It would check if `my_key` is `None` or return `"Not None"`

Comment: Could a different *real* value be required for each key currently mapped to `None`? It seems simpler to just not add the key to the `dict` and let `get` do what it is designed for.

Comment: No, it is not required to have each key a value and yes I know having the key not exist in the dict would solve my problem but I am trying to comply with the convention or design pattern(idk).

Comment: The convention would be to only store keys that map to usable values.

Comment: I think that would not be the case here since maybe the first author have a different convention in the time of writing or may have a purpose for it later on. We will never know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is to check after retrieving the value

```
my_dict = {'my_key': None}
my_value = "None Value" if my_dict.get('my_key', "") is None else my_dict.get('my_key', "")

print(my_value)
# None Value
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid calling `my_dict.get('my_key')` twice, as of Python 3.8 you could use [assignment expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) to do:

```
my_variable = "Not None" if (value := my_dict.get("my_key")) is None else value
```